# Difficulties understanding preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

Currently I'm using a small search and replace snippet for one of my WordPress sites:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'cor_remove_personal_options' ) ) {
  function cor_remove_personal_options( $subject ) {
    $pattern = '#<h3>Personal Options</h3>.+?/table>#s';
    $subject = preg_replace( $pattern, '', $subject, 1 );
    return $subject;
  }

  function cor_profile_subject_start() {
    ob_start( 'cor_remove_personal_options' );
  }

  function cor_profile_subject_end() {
    ob_end_flush();
  }
}
add_action( 'admin_head-profile.php', 'cor_profile_subject_start' );
add_action( 'admin_footer-profile.php', 'cor_profile_subject_end' );
```

Being relatively new with `preg_replace` I was wondering about the exact functionality of the opening and closing number signs `#` `#s`.

I was wondering if someone could perhaps explain this to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use / as opening and closing characters or #. If you use #, then the slash will not be taken as a special character, so this will be valid too escaping the slash character:

```
'/<h3>Personal Options<\/h3>.+?\/table>/s'
```

/s or #s means a modifier, telling to PHP that any dot in the regular expression will be evaluated as any character, including new lines.

Answer (score 1):

These sings determine start and end of the replace pattern. "s" is a modifier http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Comment: Thanks. I now somewhat understand the modifier functionality. About the number signs, could you tell when they are exactly used? I mean, I've used `preg_replace` in the past without them and am now having difficulties seeing any differences between this and any previous snippets.